# Python GUI for Caesar's cipher functions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have two functions below to encode and decode text from a text file. 
First I strip any non-alphabetic characters and convert the text to lowercase.
The encode function will shift every character in the text by a certain amount of places (number_to_rotate_by). 
Lastly, the decode function will print every possible combination of characters with the number_to_rotate_by specified.

Instead of reading from a text file, I would like to create a GUI with python to accept two inputs (string and integer) and output the cipher text.

```
import collections
import string
import re

with open('random.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n', '')

data_formatted = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', data.lower())

def encode(rotate_string, number_to_rotate_by):

    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))

encode(data_formatted,1)

def decode(test_string):
    for i in range(len(string.ascii_lowercase)):
        print(encode(data_formatted, i))

decode(data_formatted)
```

Below is what I currently have with tkinter. However, I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "5.py", line 28, in 
>       button=Button(text='Press to print', command=encode(b,0),fg='red').pack()
>     File "5.py", line 19, in encode
>       return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))
>   AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'translate'

I would appreciate any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import collections
import string

a=Tk()
a.title('Homework 1')
a.geometry('500x500+300+100')
b=StringVar()

def encode(rotate_string, number_to_rotate_by):
    c=b.get()

    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))


labl=Label(text='Please write a word or sentence',font=30).pack()

text=Entry(textvariable=b).pack()

button=Button(text='Press to print', command=encode(b,0),fg='red').pack()

a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What do you understand from it? Asterisk/star imports are discouraged, by the way.

Comment: In your post, please, code in comments is difficult to find and read.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
 File "5.py", line 28, in <module>                         
     button=Button(text='Press to print', command=encode(b,0),fg='red').pack() File "5.py", line 19, in encode return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower)) AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'translate'`

Comment: That should go in your post, too.

Comment: ***AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'translate'***: A object of type `tkinter.StringVar` is not a Python `str`. Read [Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: `command=` need function's name without `()` and arguments - ie. `command=encode`. if you uses `encode(b,0)` then first it runs `encode(b,0)` and it assign result from `encode(b,0)` as function which `command=` has to run when you click button. To assign function with arguments use `command=lambda:encode(b,0)`

Comment: if `b` is a `StringVar()` then you have to use `.get()` to get string - `b.get().translate(...)`

Comment: button can't get result from function which it executes - so using `return` in `encode()` is useless - you have to put result directly in some `Label`

Comment: common mistake - `labl = Label(..).pack()` - it assign `None` to `labl` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. if you will need access to label the you have to do it in two steps - `labl = Label(..)` and `labl.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes.

Main problem: `StringVar` need `.get()` to get string which has `.translate()`

```
b.get().translate(...)
```

Other you can see in code and read in comments above.

--

```
#import from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` not preferred
import tkinter as tk
import collections
import string

# --- functions ---

def encode(number_to_rotate_by):

    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)
    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)
    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    text = entry_text.get()

    result = text.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))

    #result_label["text"] = result
    result_text.set(result)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
entry_text = tk.StringVar()
result_text = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Please write a word or sentence')
label.pack()

text = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)
text.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result_text) # label for result
result_label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Press to print', command=lambda:encode(1))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```